# Generate jspdf auto table content from Firestore collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I already have a report created in jspdf with an autotable in its place. It will be to list some data about a student which source is in a collection in Firestore. I have already made the reference to the collection with:

```
 const ref = collection (“students”).doc(“selectedStudent”).collection(“grades”)
```

In that collection there will be an undefined number of documents. Each one of them is an object with a lot of data that I already have in place:

[image]

From all that data, I would only use three fields to dynamically fill the table, so my table code would be as:

```
doc.autoTable({
  head: [['Subject', 'Teacher', 'Achievements']],
  body: [
    ['Subject1', 'Teacher1', 'Lorem ipsum'],
    ['Subject2', 'Teacher2', 'Lorem ipsum'],
    // ...
  ],
})
```

I know that in order to achieve it I should use a forEach function or loop going through the collection but my knowledge is limited and I don’t know how to get it done. This is what I have tried:

```
let keys = ['asignatura', 'authorApellidos', 'logros'];
let bodyData = [], i, j, rowData;

    for (i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {
        rowData = [];
        for (j = 0; j < keys.length; ++j) {
          let key = keys [j];
          rowData.push (ref [i][key]);
        }
        bodyData.push (rowData);
    }

    doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Asignatura', 'Profesor', 'Descripción']],
    startY: 137,
    headStyles: { fillColor: [50, 205, 50] },
    body: bodyData
    })
```

However I have an empty table where I just see the head but no data.

When I do a console.log(ref) what I can see in the console is:

[image]

Maybe the data coming from Firebase needs to be formatted. I don't know.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @petoma, what have you tried so far? Please include it in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MarcAnthonyB. I just edited the original post to include much more information and what I have so far. I am sorry I didn't get more than that but I am trying to deal with these kind of functions in Javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `.map` to transform each item in an array into an array with same length and a different format of data

example:

```
doc.autoTable({
  head: [['Subject', 'Teacher', 'Achievements']],
  body: ref.map(object => {
    return [object.subject, object.teacher, object.achievements];
  }),
});
```

or destructure the object as follows:

```
doc.autoTable({
  head: [["Subject", "Teacher", "Achievements"]],
  body: ref.map(({subject, teacher, achievements}) => { // <-- object destructuration
    return [subject, teacher, achievements];
  }),
});
```

since this `map` function is returning new format directly, you can skip the return and make a one-liner

```
doc.autoTable({
  head: [["Subject", "Teacher", "Achievements"]],
  body: ref.map(({subject, teacher, achievements}) => [subject, teacher, achievements]),
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I have a compilation error telling me that ref.map is not a function. I assume that it has to be to the fetched data from Firestore. I am trying to get it using the for loop function. I edit the main post with the code that I tried.

Comment: you can try `Array.from(ref).map(` perhaps that'll fix the issue. What output are you getting with `console.log(ref);` ?

Comment: I tried the Array.from(ref).map( and now I don't have any compilation error but the table is empty and no data is filling the rows. I am going to update my main post to include the console.log(ref). Thank you!

Comment: is the array your are looking for in `ref.items` ? if yes: you can try `Array.from(ref.items).map(`

Comment: That was it! Now it worked. Thank you so much. I didn't get why any of the method was working. I really appreciate your help. I already marked the answer and I hope this will help other users dealing with data from Firestore. Thanks!

Comment: One last thing. I noticed there is missing a closing parentheses at the end of the last code block: "body: ref.map(({subject, teacher, achievements}) => [subject, teacher, achievements]),"

Comment: good shout, will update the response